# Caliburn Event Aggregator with multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn

I'm trying to build this project using Caliburn for the first time (and also the MEF structure, that I didn't fully understand).

I need to use both the Conductor and the EventAggregator.
The Conductor because i have an AppViewModel which "displays" 3 buttons that move the user to 3 different views (UserControls inside AppView).

And I need the EventAggregator because one of these 3 views has a button inside of it that must load 4th view (that must be a Window I think, not a UserControl, because it has to be full screen).
So I thought that when the user click this button inside the 3 view (UserControl inside AppView) a Message can be sent top the listener (that should be the AppViewModel), and this one should ActivateItem(4th vm).

I don't why but even following the examples of the projects of Caliburn my message does not reach the AppViewModel.

This is my bootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<AppViewModel>
    {
        private CompositionContainer container;

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x =>
                new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

            CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            batch.AddExportedValue(container);

            container.Compose(batch);
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
                return exports.First();

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<AppViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

This is the AppViewModel:

```
[Export (typeof(AppViewModel))]
    public class AppViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<ChangeViewEvent>
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public AppViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
        {
            events.Subscribe(this);
            ActivateItem(new MainViewModel());            
        }

        public void GoToPatientsManager()
        {
            ActivateItem(new PatientsManagerViewModel(new WindowManager(), new EventAggregator()));
        }

        public void GoToTestManager()
        {
            ActivateItem(new TestManagerViewModel(new WindowManager()));
        }

        public void GoToResultsManager()
        {
            ActivateItem(new MainViewModel());
        }

        public void Handle(ChangeViewEvent message)
        {
            switch (message.ViewName)
            {
                case "TestManager" :
                    GoToTestManager();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the view model that should launch the request for loading the 4th vm

```
 [Export(typeof(PatientsManagerViewModel))]
    public class PatientsManagerViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
        private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public PatientsManagerViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _windowManager = windowManager;
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        #region Methods

        public void ShowFakeMessage()
        {
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
            settings.PlacementTarget = GetView(null);

            var res = _windowManager.ShowDialog(new DeletePersonViewModel(), null, settings);

            if (res)
            {
                // The result of the dialog men. In this true case we'll use Linq to delete the entry from the database
                // using the dbContext
            }
        }

        public void GoToTestManager()
        {
            eventAggregator.Publish(new ChangeViewEvent("TestManager"));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

It does not reach the Handle method of the AppViewModel.

Is these something wrong with the instances of the view models? I can't move forward from here...

EDIT

Can it be that the problem is that I pass a new EventAggregator object each time I activate a new PatientsManagerViewModel? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You diagnosed your own problem. You are creating the PatientsManagerViewModel yourself and passing in a new event aggregator each time. The idea is that the event aggregator must be a singleton ie one instance shared amongst all of the view models and everything else. This is because the event aggregator stores the subscribers in memory and a new instance won't know who to inform of new events because nobody will have subscribed.

I would suggest that your `AppViewModel.GoToPatientsManager()` should look something like this:

```
public void GoToPatientsManager()
{
    var patientManagerViewModel = IoC.Get<PatientsManagerViewModel>();
    ActivateItem(patientManagerViewModel);
}
```

IoC is a (quite an ugly, hard to test) way you can access your container. You should not be creating your view models yourself, you should be getting the caliburn container do that for you instead. If the container creates your view models, then it will also fix up any dependencies that it has for you too, including the window manager and event aggregator.